# Build a ranking from a series of transitive relationships that can be noisy, inconsistent, or incomplete

Tags: algorithm, optimization, np-hard

I have a list of ~1000 different assets that I would like to rank by value for a game that I am making.

Players are given the opportunity to select one of two baskets of assets. For instance, they might be asked if they would rather have A + B or C.

From a huge list of basket preferences, I wish to rank the assets by perceived value.

Here is some example input, where accordingly players have said:

```
A > B
A + A > B + C
C > B
```

I.e. they would rather have an A than a B. they would rather have 2 As than a B and a C. Etc.

From this input, I believe the most likely value ranking is:

```
A > C > B
```

What class of algorithm should I use to attack this problem?

Sometimes the list of preferences will be contradictory (some players think A > B, others might say B > A). If I have a separate measure of player skill level, how can I leverage this to get a more accurate ranking?

I also need to be able to handle the case where there are "islands" in the  relationships between baskets. For example:

```
A > B
C > D
```

I.e. you cannot say if A <> C.

This seems to me like an optimization problem similar to various packing algorithms. Is this ranking problem NP-hard?

Answer (score 1):

It actually sounds more like graph theory to me.

Suppose you would have a digraph with *A -> B* indicating that *A < B*. Then you could

- Run a [minimum feedback set algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148103/topological-sort-of-cyclic-graph-with-minimum-number-of-violated-edges) for the ordering (which, in the absence of contradictions, is simply [Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)).
- Run DFS for the "islands" you mention.

---

So the question is how to build such a graph. I have a hunch (unfortunately not more than that yet), that the only multiple-variable rules that matter are of the form:

*A_1 + A1 + ... + A_i < A_{i + 1}*

And they should be simplified to

*A_j < A_{i + 1}, j = 1, .., i*.

(Asides from that, the only use of RHS multiple value rules would be for transitive deductions (according to my hunch), that is

*A < B + C* and *B + C < D* implies *A < D*. But this can be dealt with using dummy variables for the sums.)

---

Perhaps you should see if you can verify or contradict this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is in general impossible under reasonable assumptions by [Arrow's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem).

A better approach would be to ask the players to **score** rather than **rank**; e.g., ask them, "How many zlotys would you pay for A? For B? For C?", then average the scores for each item by the players who answered. So if only players 2, 5, and 11 answered with their estimates of the value of item A, you would add their answers and divide by 3. You could also give more weight to the answers of more experienced players.

If you still want to use baskets of assets, you can probably use linear algebra to disentangle scores for A and B based on scores for A+B and A-B, say.

If you want to make do with ranking data (e.g., if that's all you have and you can't ask any more questions), then Ami's approach is probably the best you can do.

Comment: I was not aware of Arrow's Theorem. A first blush look at the wikipedia article makes me question whether it is applicable here, but I need to think about it further. I wonder if one difference is that I seek the "most likely" ordering rather than an "objectively true" ordering. In terms of information theory, I know a lot of bits about the relative value of each item, so it seems like it should not be impossible.